# jQuery how to event fire for todays date only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I tried to fire event for today's date only.
For a reason, I can't use Date picker onselect / onClose method.

Now I want to do it directly when just select todays date from datepicker.
I'm using class for fire event. But now Working.

```
jQuery("td.ui-datepicker-today a").click(function(){ 
 //event trigger. 
});
```

Can anyone give me any suggestion ?

Comment: Try executing `console.log(jQuery("td.ui-datepicker-today a").length)` immediately before that click binding and see what it logs.

Comment: return undefined

Comment: console.log returns undefined, but a number should have printed in your console

Answer (score 3):

You may try following

```
jQuery("body").on("click","td.ui-datepicker-today a",function(){ 
 //event trigger. 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery `click` event will not work with the elements that are dynamically added to dom.
You need to use `on` or `bind` methods in jquery to achieve this.

Comment: It might be helpful if you expressed which version of `on` they should use (delegate) and perhaps provide an example, or reference to the api.  I'm not sure how `bind` would help since, especially in later version, `bind` is just a wrapper for the undelegated version of `on`.

Comment: when I use bing it trigger before click date and 'on' doesn't work